# Lambda in C# and ref/out

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have a few but similar set/get functions imported from a DLL that interface with a communication bus. These all should ideally share an identical wrapper doing some error checks, mutex handling etc. The code snippet below is a basic representation of it. It compiles and all functions seem to work except that WrappedGet() does not modify the referenced variable data. Ideas?

```
        static UInt32 common_var = 0;

        // Reduce boilerplate by wrapping all calls to the DLL with this
        static private bool CommonWrapper<T1>(Action<T1> dll_function_handle, ref T1 data)
        {
            // Commmon code for mutex handling etc
            /// .... 
            
            // Call to function handle, sometimes data is in-parameter, other times out-param
            dll_function_handle(data);
            
            return true;
        }

        static private void DllSet(UInt32 data) { common_var = data; }
        static public void WrappedSet(UInt32 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt32>((UInt32 a) => DllSet(a), ref data); }

        static private void DllGet(ref UInt16 data){ data = 1234; }
        // WrappedGet does not modify argument "data" because of the lambda? What to do?
        static public void WrappedGet(ref UInt16 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt16>((UInt16 a) => DllGet(ref a), ref data); }
```

**EDIT:**

This works:

```
  static public void WrappedGet(ref UInt16 data) 
  {
       UInt16 local = 0;
       CommonWrapper<UInt16>((UInt16) => DllGet(ref local), ref data);
       data = local;
  }
```

It is a bit awkward though, is it the right way to do this?

Comment: `dll_function_handle` is an `Action<>`... as such, its first and only parameter is used for input only and any change performed by the underlying method is lost. You better rethink `CommonWrapper`: you probably need one more overload accepting a `Func<>` delegate instead of the `Action<>` one in order to return the result.

Comment: Using `Action<>` does not seem to be the issue, see the edited answer above. Also, for the real world code I use `Func<>`.

Comment: Could someone help me point out why I got a minus one on this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in you code is that the Action does not take the parameter as a `ref` so a copy of `data` will be created before it is given to the `DllGet` method.

```
//                    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
CommonWrapper<UInt16>((UInt16 a) => DllGet(ref a), ref data);
```

Instead of an `Action` you could define a delegate and use a `ref` in the lambda.

So you need to add an delegate

```
private delegate void WrappedFunction<T>(ref T data);
```

And need to use it in the `CommonWrapper`

```
//                                    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
static private bool CommonWrapper<T1>(WrappedFunction<T1> dll_function_handle, ref T1 data)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

And you need to add the `ref` to the lambda

```
//                                                                      vvv
static public void WrappedGet(ref UInt16 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt16>((ref UInt16 a) => DllGet(ref a), ref data); }
```

So the whole code looks like this:

```
private delegate void WrappedFunction<T>(ref T data);

// Reduce boilerplate by wrapping all calls to the DLL with this
static private bool CommonWrapper<T1>(WrappedFunction<T1> dll_function_handle, ref T1 data)
{
    // Commmon code for mutex handling etc
    // .... 
    
    // Call to function handle, sometimes data is in-parameter, other times out-param
    dll_function_handle(ref data);
    
    return true;
}

static private void DllSet(UInt32 data) { common_var = data; }
static public void WrappedSet(UInt32 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt32>((ref UInt32 a) => DllSet(a), ref data); }

static private void DllGet(ref UInt16 data){ data = 1234; }
static public void WrappedGet(ref UInt16 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt16>((ref UInt16 a) => DllGet(ref a), ref data); }
```

Comment: Thank you for so carefully poiting out the points where my code failed. I tried this approach and it works. Thinking out loud, it seems the delegate function was the missing piece of the puzzle as it allows us to create a function prototype with a reference argument. That was not possible when using `Func<>` directly. I think this is the most compact and neat solution so I choose this as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, this is the solution most similar to your original code:

```
class TEST
{
    static UInt32 common_var = 0;

    // Reduce boilerplate by wrapping all calls to the DLL with this
    static private bool CommonWrapper<T1>(Action<T1> dll_function_handle, ref T1 data)
    {
        dll_function_handle(data);

        return true;
    }
    static private bool CommonWrapper<T1>(Func<T1, T1> dll_function_handle, ref T1 data)
    {
        data = dll_function_handle(data);

        return true;
    }

    static private void DllSet(UInt32 data) { common_var = data; }
    static public void WrappedSet(UInt32 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt32>((UInt32 a) => DllSet(a), ref data); }

    static private void DllGet(ref UInt16 data) { data = 1234; }
    static public void WrappedGet(ref UInt16 data) { CommonWrapper<UInt16>((UInt16 a) => { DllGet(ref a); return a; }, ref data); }
}
```

Personally, I would avoid using a `ref` parameter if any input value is discarded. I would instead declare the parameter as `out` or declare a return type for the method; this way, the `Func<T1,T1>` should be replacable with the simpler `Func<T1>`.

Comment: Aha you make the lambda return. I tried the code and it works. Unfortunately I cannot change the return type, there is already a lot of client code using these functions. It is just that we have to modify existing function internals, and we would rather not modify 1000+ lines of boiler plate code.